# How to plot gps data (csv) on a map using OpenStreetMap

Tags: python, openstreetmap, geopy, osmnx

First of all sorry for my english. 
I am working on the final project of my university career. I have the GPS data (latitude and longitude) of hundreds of students when they go to school and I have to represent these points on a map to be able to see the trajectories and have an idea about the accuracy of the GPS and clean some data.

My tutor has told me to pull this data on maps using OpenStreetMap.

I have been researching for many days and I have managed to plot the trajectories on a map of the district where the school is located but the idea is to zoom in the area where the school is located and see the points and streets with precision. I think I have to add some layers from OpenStreetMap but I do not know how to do it.

I show you the code that I've used:

```py
import osmnx as ox
import networkx as nx
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from shapely.geometry import Point, Polygon
from time import time

%matplotlib inline


place_name='Sants-Montjuïc, Barcelona, Spain' #district of school
graph=ox.graph_from_place(place_name)  
type(graph)


nodes, edges = ox.graph_to_gdfs(graph)   
nodes.head()
edges.head()
type(edges)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15,15)) 
edges.plot(ax=ax, linewidth=1, edgecolor='#BC8F8F')  


df=pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\1-MON.csv')  #csv file with the data
crs={'init': 'epsg:4326'}
df.head()

geometry=[Point(xy) for xy in zip( df["longitude"], df["latitude"])]

geo_df=gpd.GeoDataFrame(df, crs=crs, geometry=geometry)   
geo_df.head()
geo_df.plot(ax=ax, marker='o',markersize=2, color="blue")
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oVg80.png)

As I said, I want a map with a clear and expanded view of the streets in the area where the school is located, not the entire district. And plot the gps data on it.

How can I achieve it? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have a smaller map, you have to specify the desired area via a bounding box. With the coords of your bounding box you can then query data from osm. By querying all data within your bbox, you only need to plot the geometries of the objects and then add your own data points

Comment: Thanks for answering!! I Will try It as soon as I can and I Will tell you if I have been able to figure it out. (Sorry for mi english again, I'm spanish)